# how to create notification message using background process and alarm manager in android?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, intentservice

I have been struggling for days that I am not able to understand how to display a notification in the notification bar with a regular period of time (i.e., ! minute) using a background service I saw lot many code and I was totally confused when to use what. Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: notification bar or status bar?

Comment: Okay please wait for two min i am giving you working code..

Comment: Please check this link download zip code-
https://github.com/manishsri01/AndroidAlarmManagerDemo